# Error in generating a four letter character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

```
char i,j,k,l;
if(argc==2)
{

    char a[5]="\0";
    for(i='a';i<='z';i++)
    {
        a[0]=i;
        printf("%s\n",a);
        if(strcmp(crypt(a,"50"),argv[1])==0)
        {
         printf("%s\n", a);
         break;

        }
        else{
                for(j='a';j<='z';j++)
                {
                    a[1]=j;

                    if(strcmp(crypt(a,"50"), argv[1])==0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", a);
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(k='a';k<='z';k++)
                        {
                            a[2]=k;
                            if(strcmp(crypt(a,"50"), argv[1])==0)
                            {
                                printf("%s\n", a);
                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for(l='a';l<='z';l++)
                                {
                                    a[3]=l;


                                    if(strcmp(crypt(a,"50"), argv[1])==0)
                                    {
                                        printf("%s\n", a);
                                         break;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The major portion of the code is to create a set of single, double, triple and four letter strings and then check their crypted hashes across the hashed code which is passed as input
The hashing is done by the crypt function provided with c

And to check the error in my original program I used that printf line

```
printf("%s\n", a);
```

And the output which I expected was

```
a  
b  
c  
d  
e 
(...)
```

But the output was:

```
azzz  
bzzz  
czzz  
dzzz  
(...)
```

Many of the people told me to use the printf line in the inner most loop but then too it would not change the original error that my program will not be able to produce the set of single, double an triple characters. It will only be able to create a four character string.

Comment: Try changing this line: `char a[5]="\0";` to `char a[5] = {0};`

Comment: @ErikW Those initialize the same.

Comment: Replace the various `printf("%s\n", a);` with unique output to help clarify output seen.  `printf("1 <%s>\n", a);`  `printf("2 <%s>\n", a);` ...

Comment: Posting `crypt()` would help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are getting leftovers from the inner loops. So when the outer loop gets to b, a[1]..a[3] still have the 'z' character in them. Simple solution would be to do something like:

```
a[0]=i;
a[1]=0;
```

But I would simplify the loops altogether and do it that way:

```
const char END[]="zzzz"; // any word, e.g. END[]="end";
char a[sizeof(END)/sizeof(*END)]=""; // 4 chars + 1 '\0'
do{
    // increment a
    for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)-1);i++){
        if(a[i]=='z'){a[i]='a';}
        else {
            if(a[i]) a[i]+=1;
            else     a[i]='a';
            break;
        }
    }

    if(strcmp(crypt(a, "50"), argv[1])==0){
        printf("%s\n", a);
        break;
    }
} while(strcmp(a, END)); // finish on a == END
```

Not the most elegant solution, but should work. I'll leave you to fill out the rest.

Good luck.

**Bonus edit:** made the code easier to configure by adding the const up top.

Comment: thanks @MultiSkill, I get that in the result their may be left-overs from the inner loop but for the first time when the outer loop executes it must print the same as in case of a single loop simply as a  b  c  .... and then after a complete execution when the outer loop switches the value of i to 'b' then the it should give azzz  bzzz  czzz .... I am still a little bit confused Can you please clarify me on that ?

Comment: @user8590061 this is the output I get when running your code sans the crypt function:

Comment: Can you please give the output ?

Comment: @user8590061 this is the output I get when running your code sans the crypt function:
a bzzz czzz dzzz ... zzzz
So just as mentioned the leftover characters are there. Not sure where you got the azzz from, though. Like some commenters did mention: try adding a tag to know which printf the line is coming from.
I have tested my solution as well, it results in: a b c d ... z aa ba ca .. za ab bb cb db ... zzzz